# Change default login/register url in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm working with Laravel 5.6 and the out-of-the-box Login/register methods are just what I need.

I managed to remove the annoying "/public" bit on the URL by renaming server.php on the root of the "myapp" folder to index.php and then copying the .htaccess file from the /public folder to the root of myapp. In the end, my URLs look like this:

http://localhost/myapp/index.php/login

http://localhost/myapp/index.php/register

Now, I want to translate those two ugly URLs to:

http://localhost/myapp/login

http://localhost/myapp/register

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet is helping me a lot to override all authentications URLs or Routes.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

Comment: This is what Auth::routes() writes, right? Because replacing 'login' by '/login', for example, throws a 404 error when trying to access localhost/myapp/login

Comment: Yes this are all Auth::routes() you can modify how you want.

Answer (score 0):

in `routes/web.php` file

```
Route::get('/login', 'UsersController@login')->name('login');
```

I am sure it will work

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't have my own UsersController since I'm relying on the vendor's set of Auth Controllers. My routes/web.php contains Auth::routes() in order to use them, and I don't know how or if I can individually route each entry on the route:list table.

Comment: OK then you need to follow this. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-change-login-url

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that if you use linux create vhost and point you root directory to myapp/public. Or if you use windows just use laragon that will make it for u. Or use Vagrant,